# Retrieve auto-detected hibernate dialect

Tags: hibernate, dialect

Hibernate has the option to auto-detetect the `hibernate.dialect`. How can I retrieve that auto-detected value? I was unable to find any information on this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can retrieve it from the [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) but you'll need to cast it to [SessionFactoryImplementor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor.html) first:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = ...; // you should have this reference
Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getDialect();
```

The above will retrieve the dialect instance **currently being used** by session factory, which is the auto detected instance if it wasn't explicitly specified via properties.

Answer (score 7):

From Hibernate 5.2+ the most appropriate way to get Dialect is:

```
EntityManager em ...
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getJdbcServices().getDialect();
```